# Access dynamic generated div id

Tags: javascript

I have some div ids that are generated dynamicly via php

```
<div id='a<?php echo $gid?>>
```

How can I access them in JavaScript? All these divs start with "A" followed by a number.

Is there some kind of search function

```
getElementById(a*)?
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Couldn't you have PHP write some JavaScript variables with the ids?

Answer (score 1):

No generic JavaScript function for this (at least not something cross browser), but you can use the `.getElementsByTagName` and iterate the result:

```
var arrDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = 0; i < arrDivs.length; i++) {
    var oDiv = arrDivs[i];
    if (oDiv.id && oDiv.id.substr(0, 1) == "a") {
        //found a matching div!
    }
}
```

This is the most low level you can get so you won't have to worry about old browsers, new browsers or future browsers.

To wrap this into a neater function, you can have:

```
function GetElementsStartingWith(tagName, subString) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if (element.id && element.id.substr(0, subString.length) == subString) {
            result.push(element);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The usage example would be:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var arrDivs = GetElementsStartingWith("div", "a");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrDivs.length; i++) {
        arrDivs[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/vCHuL/).

In case you choose to use jQuery at some point (not worth for this thing alone) all the above code turns to single line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div[id^="a"]').css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

[Updated fiddle, with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/vCHuL/1/).

Comment: Glad to hear! You can mark this answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem, by ticking the empty V icon to the left. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a fixed id value for `getElementById` to work. However, there are other ways to search the DOM for elements (e.g. by CSS classes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) to get all divs that have an ID starting with `a`.  Then check each one to see if it contains a number.

```
var aDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="a"]');
for(var index = 0, len = aDivs.length; index < len; index++){
    var aDiv = aDivs[index];
    if(aDiv.id.match(/a\d+/)){
       // aDiv is a matching div
    }
}​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NTICompass/VaTMe/2/

Comment: this is a solution yes. But I think this is missusing the feature and is heavy load for something, that should be selected by class and then iterated over..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I question myself why you would need to select/get an element, that has a random ID. I would assume, you want to do something with every div that has a random ID (like arranging or resizing them).
In that case -> give your elements a class like "myGeneratedDivs" with the random ID (if you need it for something).
And then select all with javascript

```
var filteredResults=document.querySelectorAll(".myGeneratedDivs").filter(function(elem){
    ....
    return true;
});
```

or use jQuery/Zepto/YourWeaponOfChoice

```
var filteredResults=$(".myGeneratedDivs").filter(function(index){
    var elem=this;
    ....
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use jQuery, you can use following jQuery selectors

```
div[id^="a"]
```

or

```
$('div[id^="id"]').each(function(){
// your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to target the parent div and when someone click on child div inside a parent div then you can catch the child div.

```
 <div id="target">
  <div id="tag1" >tag1</div>
  <div id="tag1" >tag2</div>
  <div id="tag1" >tag3</div>
 </div>

$("#target").on("click", "div", function() {
var showid = $(this).attr('id');
alert(showid)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

getElementById() will return the exact element specified. There are many javascript frameworks including [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that allow much more powerful selection capabilities. eg:

1. Select an element by id: $("#theId")
2. Select a group of elements by class: $(".class")
3. Select subelements: $("ul a.action")

For your specific problem you could easily construct the appropriate selector.